# kafka connect -> pubsub -> dataflow pipeline data loss

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-beam, apache-kafka-connect, google-cloud-pubsub, dataflow

I'm creating a streaming data pipeline that streams data from a kafka cluster to Google BQ.
Currently, I am pushing these data to pubsub through pubsub kafka connector, then from pubsub to BQ through dataflow.

However, in some cases, there are some data which have seems to gone missing at certain times.
For a whole day of data, about 300k rows, there seems to be 17 rows on average missing.

[image: Missing data]

It only happens on a certain time (refer to image)
When I check the logs for kafka connector, the data is present in the logs and there isn't any errors found :

```
[2019-11-26 13:30:01,618] INFO Key record: Struct{ad_id=95177783,action_id=2,state_id=999113806} (com.google.pubsub.kafka.sink.CloudPubSubSinkTask)
[2019-11-26 13:30:01,618] INFO Value record: Struct{ad_id=95177783,action_id=2,state_id=999113806,state=activated,transition=activate,timestamp=Struct{DateTime=Struct{year=2019,month=11,day=26,hour=13,minute=30,second=1,micro=602125}},remote_addr=202.184.54.140,remote_browser=} (com.google.pubsub.kafka.sink.CloudPubSubSinkTask)
[2019-11-26 13:30:01,618] INFO data: {"ad_id":95177783,"action_id":2,"state_id":999113806,"state":"activated","transition":"activate","timestamp":{"DateTime":{"year":2019,"month":11,"day":26,"hour":13,"minute":30,"second":1,"micro":602125},"SpecialTime":null},"remote_addr":"202.184.54.140","remote_browser":"","token_id":null,"old_token_id":null,"auth_admin_id":null,"auth_store_id":null,"auth_store_email":null} (com.google.pubsub.kafka.sink.CloudPubSubSinkTask)
```

This is the example log for the state_id = 999113806. A unique row identifier.
However, I'm not able to find any log in the pubsub logs for the same data.

Hence, I'm kinda lost here. Did kafka conenctor successfully send the data over and did pubsub successfully receive it ?

Or is this a problem with dataflow reading all records from pubsub ?

My dataflow code is literally:

```
class transform_class(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element, publish_time=beam.DoFn.TimestampParam, *args, **kwargs):
        logging.info(element)

def run(output_path, window_size=1.0, pipeline_args=None):
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(
        pipeline_args, streaming=True, save_main_session=True)

    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as pipeline:
        lines = (pipeline 
                | 'Read PubSub Messages' >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(topic='pubsubtopic',with_attributes = True)
                | 'Transforming Messages' >> beam.ParDo(transform_class()))
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Out of interest, since you have data in Kafka have you considered using Kafka Connect to stream the data to BigQuery directly?

Comment: What windowing strategy did you use? Fixed time, sliding time, session, single global window?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt we want to be able to scale and manage data with dataflow

Comment: @manesioz no windowing strategy as i am using streaming inserts

Comment: Kafka Connect scales also, as well as managing delivery, offsets, etc.  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ :) http://rmoff.dev/ksldn19-kafka-connect